# Testing full calender with protractor-angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, protractor, fullcalendar

I have built an angular2 project and I am trying to test the end to end functionality using protractor. I am using jquery Full calendar . I have used multiple date selection function using which I can slide to select start and end dates and post the data to server. I am very new to protractor and I am not understanding how slide to select those dates and test it.

Comment: Please add problem description with more information or share the HTML which will help in solving this issue?